# How to upgrade ROS 2 Foxy to Humble in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I have a straightforward query, but I want to confirm that I'm on the right track before moving forward. Right now, I'm utilizing ROS1 Noetic and ROS2 Foxy on Ubuntu 20.04. However, I need to transition to ROS2 Humble because the packages I require are available in Humble.

My intention is to upgrade from Foxy to Humble on Ubuntu 20.04. Is this feasible? I've read that Humble might necessitate Ubuntu 20.04. If it is doable, could you please guide me on how to proceed with the upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

There are the following ways to get started with Humble in Ubuntu 20.04:

1. [Using Docker](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Run-2-nodes-in-single-or-separate-docker-containers.html)
2. [Using source compilation](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html)
3. [Using LXD containers](https://ubuntu.com/blog/install-ros-2-humble-in-ubuntu-20-04-or-18-04-using-lxd-containers)

I recommend opting for the first approach since it is the simplest. The second approach might require you to find workarounds in case of compilation errors. To provide a completeness of this answer, I am sharing a link to the third approach.

Answer (score 0):

Ros2 Humble requires Ubuntu 22.04 or better. Unless you use a container of some sort.